# Value cannot be null Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, webservice-client

I'm consuming a webservice following method:

```
wsSascar2.SasIntegraWSClient w2 = new wsSascar2.SasIntegraWSClient();
List<wsSascar2.pacotePosicao> lista = w2.obterPacotePosicoes("user", "password", 0).ToList();
```

But the following error is returned:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

The problem is in my code or the return of the webservice?

Webservice: http://sasintegra.sascar.com.br/SasIntegra/SasIntegraWSService?wsdl

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value from `obterPacotePosicoes` is null. Try to use `??` operator and provide default empty array.

```
List<wsSascar2.pacotePosicao> lista = 
    (w2.obterPacotePosicoes("user", "password", 0) 
    ?? new wsSascar2.pacotePosicao[0])
        .ToList();
```

As [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can't accept null value on the source parameter.

> ArgumentNullException source is null.

Comment: Thanks for efficiency in response. Helped a lot, I think that's the problem. I will contact the person responsible for the webservice.

Comment: Here are some linq code examples that will give you an argument null exception:

Comment: `List<Myobj> myList = null;
            //from this point on, any linq statement you perform on this object will throw an argument null exception:
            myList.ToList();
            myList.GroupBy(m => m.Id);
            myList.Count();
            myList.Where(m => m.Id == 0);
            myList.Select(m => m.Id == 0);
            //etc...`

Answer (score 0):

I think the service is returning null.
try the below code

```
wsSascar2.SasIntegraWSClient w2 = new wsSascar2.SasIntegraWSClient();
List<wsSascar2.pacotePosicao> lista  = new List<wsSascar2.pacotePosicao>(); 
var result = w2.obterPacotePosicoes("user", "password", 0);
if(result != null)
   lista  = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for efficiency in response. Helped a lot, I think that's the problem. I will contact the person responsible for the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a case getting 'value cannot be null' when consuming an web-services under WPF app.

Eventually, such error went away after free some diskspace, double verified by fill-up the disk , same error thrown again.

Hope this help.